# How do I take a partial quotation that ends with a question mark (but not within my quote)?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I am in the process of writing a paper on Shakespeare's Macbeth, and I want to take a quotation from the following passage:

> Which thou esteem'st the ornament of life
>   And live a coward in thine on esteem,
>   Letting "I dare not" wait upon "I would"
>   Like the poor cat i' the adage?

However I only want to take the first three lines of the passage:

> It is written, "Which thou esteem'st the ornament of life / And live a coward in thine on esteem, / Letting "I dare not" wait upon "I would"...

How should I punctuate the end (*...*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could punctuate thus:

> 'Which thou esteem'st the ornament of life / And live in a coward in thine on esteem, / Letting "I dare not" wait upon "I would" . . . ?'

It is then obvious that you are quoting a question, but not including the entire sentence.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. This is what I'm going to be using for my paper, so I'll go ahead and mark it as the answer.